# Issue with Adwaita Dark theme: still using regular Adwaita titlebars

Tags: 11.10, themes, gnome-tweak-tool

I downloaded and installed the Adwaita Dark theme. It worked, but I had an issue. The title bar was supposed to turn black too, but it doesn't. I followed the steps in [this OMG! Ubuntu article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/use-adwaita-dark-as-your-system-theme.). There is a screenshot in the site with the title bars black.
And here is a screenshot of my Ubuntu.

[image]

As you can see, I applied the Adwaita theme in "Window theme" too but it stays just like the default Adwaita.

Why does that happen and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried logging out and logging back in, or a reboot? This sometimes fixes common issues with switching themes.

Comment: Yes. First of all I tried `compiz --replace`. Then I tried restarting the session. But none of those worked.

Comment: I'm using this theme right now, as a matter of fact, under GNOME Shell and it did the switch properly for me. As I see you're using Unity, I'm not sure if that changes anything; I don't have any further ideas.

Comment: I tested it under gnome-shell and it worked. The issue seems to be with Unity, like you said.

Answer (score 2):

*(Comment to answer by OP)*

I tested it under gnome-shell and it worked. The issue seems to be with Unity, like you said. – Jesse Nov 9 '11 at 4:49